# Clickable area without blocking text selection?

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to achieve a clickable area within an element, without preventing the user from selecting the text underneath?

I know the exact position of the area on my screen in pixels along with dimensions (pdf viewer), however, placing a div over the text with click event prevents the user from selecting the text.

Is there a way to achieve this without blocking select? EG: Recieve click event, but don't block text selection?

Comment: unclear what you are doing that would prevent them from selecting the text. Can you show what you actually did?

Comment: Apologies I should have made it clearer. I don't actually know where in the text by character the area is to select, I only know the absolute position in pixels of the area where  the characters appear on the page. This is not a standard html document. I am using an absolute div on top of the page using pixel coordinates provided to me via an API. Was hoping to let the div 'pass through' clicks whilst still registering them itself

Comment: I have edited my question to better reflect what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: You would be better wrapping the content inline with a tag than adding a layer above it. If you were to ignore the click on the layer it is simple as a pointer event, but since you want to know about the click, that can not be done.

Comment: Did you find a solution? Can the clickable _hotspot_ div be placed underneath the text (instead of above)? Scale the hotspot in such a way that it is smaller than "word". This way "word" is still selectable from the edges, but clicking a more central part of "word" will now hit the hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like this:

```js
document.getElementById('clickable').onclick = () => alert(1234);
```

```html
<div>
  ABCD<span id="clickable">E</span>FGH
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
<div id='test'>
Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

```
// preventing text selection on the element with id 'test'
document.getElementById('test').onselectstart = (e) => {e.preventDefault()};

// show content of element with id 'test' in console log when clicking on text
document.getElementById('test').onclick = (e) => {console.log(document.getElementById('test').textContent)};
```